# AngularJSで1画面に複数のスクロールをいれられますか

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ui-router

AngularJSでルーティングはui routerを使用してダッシュボードのようなものを作成しています。そこで質問なのですが、1画面に複数のスクロール可能なリストを入れることはできるのでしょうか。例えば左のリストをクリックしたら、右のViewにあるリストの内容が変化するような実装をしたいです。可能であればやり方を教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1画面に複数のスクロール可能なリストを入れることはできるのでしょうか。

これを実現できるかはCSSの書き方に依存します。Angular であるかどうかは関係ありません。

以下のサンプルの `overflow-y: auto;` に着目してください。これが指定された要素の中身の高さが `height: 250px`; よりも大きい場合、自動でスクロールできるようになります。同じような要素が2つあることで、それぞれ独立してスクロールできる要素を複数1画面に収めることができます。

要素をスクロール可能にするには、`overflow` を指定した上で、その高さが中身に依存しない=中身のほうが大きくなることが重要です。この例では `display: inline-block` (もしくは `display: block` も使える) に加えて、`height` を指定することで実現していますが、他にも方法は考えられます。まずは一例として参考まで。

```css
.container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;

  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 250px;
  
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.left {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

._stage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="_stage">
  <div class="container left">
    <ul>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
      <li>Foo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container right">
    <ul>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
      <li>Bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました!